# How To Move The TabBarView in the Center to The Top of the Page?

Tags: flutter, listview, scroll, tabs

I have a TabBarView in the middle of the page which changes tab. The content on tab 1 is created by StaggeredGridView.countBuilder while content on 2nd tab is created by listview.builder.

The content of each tab is scrollable, however, only the content below the TabBarView is scrollable.

Is it possible that as I scroll the page, the TabBarView also moves from the middle of the screen to the top of the page and locks itself there, so that the entire screen can be filled with content from each tab?

I've seen people suggesting using SingleChildScrollView for the body and physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() for the listview.builder.

This has not worked. The screen returns just the background color when it is run.

[image: Current TabBarView Position]

[image: Desired TabBarView Position when scrolled.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a custom scrollView which holds all the items.

1. Your profile details widget
2. tabBar
3. tabview

lets implement this

con: appbar cannot be pinned

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyCustomScrollViewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyCustomScrollViewScreenState createState() =>
      _MyCustomScrollViewScreenState();
}

class _MyCustomScrollViewScreenState extends State<MyCustomScrollViewScreen>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController tabController;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverAppBar(
              floating: true,
              title: Text("AppBar"),
            ),
            //profile widget

            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              key: UniqueKey(),
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                height: 100,
                child: Center(child: Text("Profile details")),
              ),
            ),

            //tabbar
            SliverPersistentHeader(
                pinned: true,
                floating: true,
                delegate: MyCustomHeader(
                    expandedHeight: kToolbarHeight,
                    tabs: TabBar(
                      controller: tabController,
                      tabs: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.ac_unit,
                          size: 30,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.access_alarm,
                          size: 30,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ))),
            //children
            SliverFillRemaining(
              child: TabBarView(
                controller: tabController,
                children: [
                  Center(child: Text("I'm 1")),
                  Center(child: Text("I'm 2"))
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// persistent header
class MyCustomHeader extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  MyCustomHeader({
    @required this.expandedHeight,
    this.tabs,
    this.context,
  });

  final Widget tabs;
  final double expandedHeight;
  final BuildContext context;

  @override
  double get maxExtent => expandedHeight;

  @override
  double get minExtent => kToolbarHeight;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) => true;

  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return Container(
      child: tabs,
    );
  }
}
```

here is the result

[img url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/od0I0.jpg)

Comment: you got me Griffins, this is exactly what i want.

Comment: Griffins, is it possible to add a normal app bar in the SliverAppBar? Bcos I would like to have a chevron_left icon on the top left of the appBar for users to navigate back to previous page.

Comment: Another qtn Griffins. the widget of my tabbarview is not scrollable, which is good, bcos that achieves the scrolling of the whole page which includes the profile.
However, the content can't be further scrolled down after it reaches the page's length. The content is abruptly cut off.
By any chance, you know why?

Comment: sorry for the delayed response, yeah a sliver appbar has appbar like properties

Comment: need more details on the widgets, ideally if this two `StaggeredGridView.countBuilder` and `listview.builder` scroll is disabled you should be able to view all items and scroll

Comment: thanks! By any chance, you know how to solve this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67629779/reflect-list-data-back-into-ui-flutter

Comment: I'm also having bottom overflow issue when using this method. All TabBarView child are non-scrollable.

Comment: I end up wrapping each child of TabBarView under a SingleChildScrolView and disabling the scrolling physics. It works now. Thanks. It really helps.